# Как скачать файл, который создал бот aiogram?

Tags: aiogram

Бот создал файл, который лежит на сервере вместе с ботом. Как его может скачать пользователь бота?

Comment: Вероятно, бот должен вернуть пользователю какую-то ссылку на сгенерированный им файл

Answer (score 0):

Отвечу сам себе.
Вероятно есть два варианта:

Первый, как посоветовали в комментарии, отправить пользователю прямую ссылку на файл. Сработает, если на сервере включен http протокол.
Второй способ. После создания файла слать его пользователю.

```
        with open(f'./media/{file_name}.mp3', 'rb') as audio:
            await bot.send_audio(call.from_user.id, audio,
                                 caption=f'Mp3 audio is created.\n')


        with open(f'./media/{file_name}', 'rb') as video:
            await bot.send_video(call.from_user.id, video,
                                 caption=f'Mp4 video is created.\n')
```

Но в этом случае, у телеграма есть ограничение на размер файла, с видео будут проблемы.